# Making pPayments with PayPal

Tags: php, paypal, payment

I want to process PayPal payment to PayPal user from my account. I fetch form details with PHP script from my server, however, I am not able to process the payment using PHP script only (I suppose PayPal website requires user to have JavaScript on the client side to login and complete payment, so it is not possible to do that with CURL simply). Is it somehow possible to make a payment with PayPal using API, passing all this information along?

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" name="paypal">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="RECIPIENT">
    <input type="hidden" name="undefined_quantity" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="INVOICE">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="10788650">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="8.76">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://some.page.lt/payments/paypal.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://some.page.lt/rodyti.php?id=MTA3ODg2NTAJLTE1MjY3MDY0ODc">
    <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="windows-1257">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
</form>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards,
Jonas

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_documentation

Hope this helps you to understand the paypal better.

Thanks